# How to print <DummyText> inside html tag using javascript?

Tags: html

I need to show "<>" symbols for my string "DummyText". When i run and inspect the element, it converted to be DOM element in HTML like . This is the code I am trying to do

```
<p><a href='' title='Survey Link'><DummyText></a></p>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead, from [here](https://brajeshwar.github.io/entities/)

```html
<p><a href='' title='Survey Link'>&lt;DummyText&gt;</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

For HTML you have to encode special characters:

```html
<p><a href='' title='Survey Link'>&lt;DummyText&gt;</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `&lt;` to display **<** and `&gt;` to display **>** in HTML

```js
document.getElementById('anc').innerHTML="&lt;Dummy Text&gt;";
```

```html
<p><a id="anc" href='' title='Survey Link'></a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that the reserved characters `<>` are being parsed as HTML. Since `<Dummy Text>` doesn't exist as a tag, it swallows it so that it doesn't appear on your page.

To fix this you need to use HTML character codes. Instead of inserting the symbol `<` use the string `&lt;` and instead of `>` use `&gt;`